# Powershell - Get a list of users from an admin group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm a beginner in programming in general, and I'm trying to create a powershell script that will:

-Connect to a virtual controller

-Get a list of all active directory users with access to it

-If the list contains an active directory group, it will pull the list of individuals in that group.

This is what I have so far:

```
connect-viserver vcxx.com
import-module ActiveDirectory
Write-Host "---Admins---"
Get-VIPermission | where {$_.Role -eq "Admin"} | Select Role, UID
```

This is what it shows back:

```
Role      : Admin
Uid       : /VIServer\user/Datacenter/Permission=Admin-CORP\xxxAdmins-group/
```

Now I would want the script to look at the last part of the UID for the keyword *group* **OR** *admins* and if it finds it then it'll do:

```
Get-ADGroupMember xxxAdmins-Group |Get-ADUser -Properties *|select name, account |ft -AutoSize
```

Please let me know if something is not clear.
I appreciate any guidance.

---

This is what I have now, after some help from @Chakani

```
$VIPerms =  Get-VIPermission | where {$_.Role -eq "Admin"} | Select UID
$UID = $VIPerms.UID
$ADGroup = $UID -replace '.+\\(.+)/$','$1'
$ADGroupArray  = $ADgroup -split '\s'
$ADSplit = Foreach($i in $ADGroupArray){If($i -match '(admins|group)') {$i -split "-group"}}
$ADSplit
$Users  = Foreach($j in $ADSplit){Get-ADGroupMember $j|Get-ADUser -Properties *|select givenname, surname, samaccountname }
$Users | select givenname, surname, samaccountname | ft -autosize
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what would work best here would be to use one of the powershell regex operators in this  case, and would look like this:

Assign the UID Output of your cmdlet to a variable, then parse that and if it matches what you're looking for (sounds like either Admins or group in that final section, between '' and '/', if I understand correctly) trim it to what you need, then drop that in to the Get-ADGroupMember.

If all of the preceeding structure of the UID's is consistently going to be structured the same, I would do the replacement first, then match what's left against what you're looking for, as below:

```
$VIPerms =  Get-VIPermission | where {$_.Role -eq "Admin"} | Select Role, UserID
$UID = $VIPerms.UID
$ADGroup = $UID -replace '.+\\(.+)/$','$1'
If($ADGroup -match '(admins|group)'){

     Get-ADGroupMember $ADGroup |Get-ADUser -Properties *|select name, account |ft -AutoSize
}
```

Make certain to use single quotes around the '$1', so that you get the regex value of "1st group" as opposed to the variable $1.

Comment: I can't see what its doing, if I comment the part I wrote I dont get anything back.
Can you tell me what this part is doing?
`$UID -replace '\\(.+)/$','$1'`

Comment: Ach, I missed one bit: that line should be  `$UID -replace '.+\\(.+)/$','$1'`
This should basically parse the entire UID (you may have to change the `$UID=$VIPerms.UID` line up above if the actual property is labeled userID)  and then replace it with everything contained in the (.+) part of it which is essentally "everything that shows up between a '\' and a '/', then store that in the $ADGroup variable. That .+ that I missed at the beginning is rather important, my apologies.

Comment: Ahh I see that works. Now for the if statement I'm getting this:
`Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.
+      Get-ADGroupMember $ADGroup |Get-ADUser -Properties *|select name ...
+                        ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember`

Comment: Can you post the results of `$ADGroup | Format-List *` here? It seems the string we want may be stored as a particular key value pair in that object. `$ADGroup | Get-Member` should also give us the properties available to that object, it may just be a case of needing to specify `Get-ADGroupMember $ADGroup.someProperty` though I'm not 100% certain on that one and may have to see the output of those other commands first.

Comment: r1234-user

XXXAdmins-group

YYYAdmins-group

PXX00111-Admins-group

Administrators-group

pxxx-user

Administrator-user

Comment: Ah so it looks like what we need to do here is : after `$ADGroup = $UID -replace '.+\\(.+)/$','$1'`, we need to split that line in to each one of the individual groups and then run them through a foreach loop. It should be something like this `$ADGroupArray  = $ADgroup -split '\s'`, which should split it based off of white space, then run that through a foreach loop, so


`$Users  = Foreach($i in $ADGroupArray){If($i -match '(admins|group)'){Get-ADGroupMember $i|Get-ADUser -Properties *|select name, account
}
}`
And then output and format:
`$Users | select name, account | ft -autosize`

Comment: Alright thats working! 
Now what I get back is `Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'PXX-Admins-group'
That's because the AD group is called PXX-Admins, not PXX-Admins-group.

Comment: I tried to do a `-split "-group"` but now I don't know how to tell it to use the first part of the split and ignore the rest of the array..

Comment: I edited the original post so you can see what I have now

Comment: Ahhh you may have to scrub the -group from the end in that case, which would basically be adding a line in that foreach loop before the get-adgroupmember that would be something like `$i = $i -replace '-group',''` if that -group ending is always in error. You may have to modify it a bit to account for various other cases if there are any .